# Type of Dynamic object and GUI-construction for file import

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

It's not clear what the Dynamic objects really are. For example, if I define the following

```
x=1;
Dynamic[x];
y=Dynamic[x];
```

we can see that all the three are changing simultaneously but `NumberQ[x]` gives `True` while `NumberQ[y]` and `NumberQ[Dynamic[x]]` give `False`. In fact, I don't know what they are, they are neither string nor other type. So what are their type and how to transform them into other type I need ?

More specifically, this question is encountered when I try to design a GUI in which I should have been able to input some file(data) by clicking the `browse` button. The code is presented,

```
DynamicModule[{path = "", data = "", status = 0},
Panel@
Column@
{Row@{"Input:",
  FileNameSetter[Dynamic[FindFile@path,
    (path = #; If[(path =!= $Failed || path =!= $Canceled) &&
        FileExistsQ@path, data = Flatten@Import@path; 
       status = 1]) &],
   "Open", {".dat" -> {"*.dat"}}],
  InputField[Dynamic@path, String, Enabled -> False]
  },
If[Dynamic[status] === 1, Dynamic@ListPlot[data],
 Print["Please input file"]]
}]
```

As you see, since I don't know the type of Dynamic object, `===` is used. But the `If` doesn't work here. Even if I choose the file I need, it just does not execute the right action.

So, does anybody know the problem or you may just have a better solution to realize such functionality ? Thank you.

(Btw, once the file is loaded and data is set, more sophisticated operation such as data analysis and other interactive manipulation shall be made.)

Comment: You need to go back to the drawing board unfortunately. `Dynamic` is not what you apparently think it is ...but what it **is** is explained in detailed in the docs and various tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to start with `Dynamic` is the docs, in particular the tutorials. For me at least, I think the best way to think of `Dynamic` is that it dynamically updates pixels on your screen. This means that if something is not displayed `Dynamic` has no effect whatsoever ...other than possible deleterious effects that you have discovered.

`NumberQ[y]` cannot possible ever be `True` because your are asking whether something with head `Dynamic` is a number, which quite clearly it is not. If you want to test something that has `Dynamic` around it you would need to strip that away:

```
NumberQ[y]
NumberQ[y /. Dynamic -> Identity]
NumberQ[Setting@y]
(* False *)
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Likewise, `Dynamic[status] === 1` will always be `False`. I don't know what you data looks like -- are you sure you need `FindFile` (?) -- but this change to your code will work subject to the caveat that you understand your data and you understand `Import` and `ListPlot`

```
DynamicModule[{path = "", data = "", status = 0},

 Panel@Column[{
    Row[{"Input:", 
      FileNameSetter[
       Dynamic[path, (path = #; 
          If[(path =!= $Failed || path =!= $Canceled) && 
            FileExistsQ@path, data = Flatten@Import[path, "Data"];
           status = 1]) &], "Open", {".dat" -> {"*.dat"}}], 
      InputField[Dynamic@path, String, Enabled -> False]}],
    Dynamic@If[status === 1,
      ListPlot[data],
      "Please input file"]
    }]
 ]
```